# Matrices globales en Laravel

Tags: laravel, clase

Estoy creando un proyecto en Laravel que usa una matriz de datos definida por programación. Esta matriz se debe usar en varios controladores, y querría no tener que copiarla en cada uno. En su lugar, me gustaría crearla en un solo archivo (como propiedad de una clase, por ejemplo), y luego poder importar esa clase en donde la necesite, como una inyección de dependencias.

Sin embargo, no encuentro ningún comando Artisan para crear una clase "genérica". Se debe hacer manualmente? O hay alguna técnica de Laravel específica para esto?

Comment: Este tipo de preguntas no son bien recibidas porque sus respuestas se basan en opiniones. En estos casos puedes acudir al chat global y preguntar por allí. Y si en definitiva puedes crear manualmente la clase y utilizarla en los controladores donde lo necesites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso lo mejor es crear un archivo dentro del directorio `config`. En ese archivo metes las matrices o variables que vayas a usar. Supón que tu archivo lo llamas, digamos, `mydata.php`, y en su interior metes esto:

```
<?php
    return [
        'meses' => [
            '01'    =>  'Enero',
            '02'    =>  'Febrero',
            '03'    =>  'Marzo',
            '04'    =>  'Abril',
            '05'    =>  'Mayo',
            '06'    =>  'Junio',
            '07'    =>  'Julio',
            '08'    =>  'Agosto',
            '09'    =>  'Septiembre',
            '10'    =>  'Octubre',
            '11'    =>  'Noviembre',
            '12'    =>  'Diciembre',
        ],
    ];
```

Los archivos que están en el directorio `config` están disponibles, automáticamente, en toda la aplicación, por lo que no tienes que importar específicamente tu archivo. Simplemente, en los controladores donde necesites esa matriz, harías algo así:

```
$meses = config('mydata.meses');
```

Y ya tienes la matriz en la variable `$meses`.

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba saber. Gracias.